# Bash: How to check to see if a file is still in use

Tags: bash, while-loop

I currently have a bash script that looks at a file and stores some of the data as a variable... I only want that to happen if the file is not being updated.

I was thinking of using something like:

```
touch "/path/tofile/temp.txt"
while [[ test "/path/tofile/temp.txt" -nt "/path/tofile/readme.txt" ]]
do
echo "readme is still updating"
else? move on???
```

Comment: Maybe useful: http://askubuntu.com/q/14252/143251

Comment: Unclear question.  Do you really want to check whether the file _currently_ is _being_ updated?  That's not possible because there is no such _state_ officially.  All you can do is look whether some other process has an open file handle on the file (using `lsof` or similar tools).  But your approach comparing the file times hints on that you want to do something else like finding out whether the file has changed since some specific time.  Is this the case?

Comment: "looks at a file and stores some of the data as a variable": what, exactly, does that mean? What is it you want to do if the file is *not* being updated (assuming you could determine that precisely).

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach for this is to write the file with a temporary name and rename it to the "official" name when it's ready to be used by other processes. That way, you can avoid a whole slew of problems. Even if this seems like a lot of work, you should really consider this.

Alternatively, you could use a lock folder: Have the updating process and your script create a folder on disk. As long as the folder exists, the other process is working on the file so the current process needs to wait. Drawback: Once in a while, an error will happen and the lock folder will stay around and you'll have a deadlock.

Or you can use `lsof` to see if there is a process that has this file open for writing ... but that doesn't mean this information is still true when you start reading the file.

So again: Use a temporary name and rename the file when it's ready. Really. Everything else might work sometimes. Is that really something you would like to tell you boss?